# Hacer comparación de dos variables

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, livewire

Tengo un usuario que va asociado a un área
La cual llamo de la siguiente manera

```
$this->idArea = auth()->user()->id_area;
```

Estoy sacando el ID del área del usuario actual. Ejemplo en este caso el usuario actual tiene área 7

```
{{ $idArea }} imprime: 7
```

Tengo la siguiente tabla category_areas

```
+----+-------------+---------+
| id | id_category | id_area |
+----+-------------+---------+
| 12 |          35 |       9 |
| 14 |           1 |       7 |
| 18 |          35 |       3 |
| 20 |          35 |       7 |
| 21 |          18 |       9 |
+----+-------------+---------+
```

De ahí realice un Select

```
// Select categorías según el area del usuario logeado
        $this->areacategory = categoryarea::where('id_area', $this->idArea)->get();
        $this->idcategory =  $this->areacategory->pluck('id_category');
        $this->categories = Category::whereIn('id', $this->idcategory)->get();
```

**El cual funciona bien**

Al seleccionar la categoría 35 me trae este resultado **[9,3,7]**

Ahora tengo esta consulta

```
$this->idareaycategory = categoryarea::where('id_category', $this->id_category)->get();
        $this->idareaycategory2 =  $this->idareaycategory->pluck('id_area');
```

**esta mal y no se como hacer**

estoy intentado sacar del **[9,3,7]** el numero 7 ya que es el id_area del usuario actual logeado

Para poder obtener tanto el id_area relacionada con id_category y su ID que sería lo siguiente [20,35,7], de la tabla anterior

Gracias

Comment: lo que quiero hacer en realidad es un select dependiente de 3 niveles, en este casoa iría area->categoría->actividad, como el area ya lo tre el usuario pues realice el select categoría a partir de id del usuario logeado, ese es la premiara parte y funciona bien, ahora resulta para poder seguir con el otro select necesito toma el ID de la tabla category_areas que es lo que intento hacer no puedo sacar el id de esa tabla

Comment: de donde sacas el 20,35,37??? esos datos no los veo en la tabla

Comment: si ya tiene el id 7 con esto: `$this->idArea` no le veo sentido intentar extraer el 7 del array ... sera que quieres comprobar que el id 7 existe en el array usa entonces  `in_array()` Link del manual: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.in-array.php

Comment: o para el `select` usa `whereIn()`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30706671/4717133 y este es el manual de referencia: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#where-clauses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré la solución

estaba haciendo una consulta de mas que era traer la array `[9,3,7]`, omití esa consulta y tome el mas bien id que sale del Select categorías el cual me trae la categoría `[35]`,

Teniendo el ID Categoría y el ID de area del usuario actual los cuales son
`[35]` y `[7]`, realice una doble consulta (no se si se llama doble consulta) para traer id de tabla category_areas

```
$this->idareaycategory = categoryarea::where([['id_category', $this->selecteCategory],['id_area', $this->idArea]])->get();
```

lo cual me trae lo siguiente

```
[{"id":20,"id_category":35,"id_area":7,"ans_cat":null,"duration_cat":null,"description":null,"created_at":"2021-07-13T21:17:22.000000Z","updated_at":"2021-07-13T21:17:22.000000Z"}]
```

de hay tomo el id con lo sigunete

```
$this->idareaycategory2 =  $this->idareaycategory->pluck('id');
```

lo cual me da como resultado `[20]` que es lo que necesito para realizar el siguiente select dependiente

Gracias...